# Update multiple users by passing list of User ids

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am trying to update some user information by passing List of User-Ids as parameter
i want to update isActive field of User fo which i am passing the user ids.
Below is my controller

```
@PutMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping("/UserUpdate")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUsers(List<Long> userIds) {

        **userService.updateUsers(userIds);**       

         return ResponseEntity.ok(200);
    }
```

updateUsers() is a method in my Service where i have to write the logic 
I tried something like below but it's not working

```
public void updateUsers(List<Long> userIds) {
         List<Users> userList= userRepository.findAll();

          for (Long i : userIds) {


                  for ( Users user : userList)

                  {
                      if(userRepository.findById(i) != null)
                      {
                      user.setIsActive(9L);
                      user.setUserName("Update Test");
                      }
```

my dto

```
 public class UserDto {
    private     List<Users> userList;
     private  String appName="Users Project";
   // getters and setters removed for brevity
```

And my Users entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class Users {

@Id
@Column(name="USER_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long userId;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String userName;

@Column(name="ACTIVE")
private Long isActive;
```

// getters and setters removed for brevity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void updateUsers(List<Long> userIds) {
   for (Long i : userIds) {
      User user = userRepository.findById(i);
         if(user != null){
            user.setIsActive(9L);
            user.setUserName("Update Test");
            // call your update method here (this is not stated in your code)
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use the following code

```
@Modifying
@Query("update Users u set u.isActive = ?1, u.userName = ?2 where u.userId in ?3")
void updateUsers(Long isActive, String userName, List<Long> userId);
```

Add this code in your userRepository and use the method.

Comment: No this is a bad approach

Comment: Any reason behind this @RajR